# Call WSO2 DSS service using ajax?

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-identity-server

I have one data service in WSO2 DSS. And also its possible to call using browsers.But i can't make a request using ajax to call this service.I think CORS issue is occurring.So i want to add Access-Control-Allow-Origin parameter to response header.How this is possible in WSO2 DSS ,Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can put a custom headers by adding axis2 custom out flow handler.

http://shivendra-tripathi.blogspot.com/2010/04/adding-handler-in-axis2.html?m=1
http://shivendra-tripathi.blogspot.com/2010/04/adding-soap-header-in-axiom.html?m=1