# CORS Issue in WSO2 DSS By using Ajax

Tags: ajax, cors, wso2-data-services-server

> Calling **Wso2** **Dss** Services by using ajax is not working like Rest Resource or SOAP UI it causes

Cors Issue , Even i did not get any relevant information about that after a long research What i have to edit in my Configuration File or is some other option is there to fix this issue.

This Case For my apache tomcat Server ,  i can Simply add Access Control Orgin header as * , but in wso2 its not working out .I dont know even where to add it ..plz give me a good solution for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may set up WSO2 ESB on before of your DSS server and you may call your service using ESB proxy or REST end point.If you do that you can set CORS parameters  inside outSequence tag.
Same question asked here [Call WSO2 DSS service using ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22086327/call-wso2-dss-service-using-ajax)

Comment: Thank You Sir i have did this and added OutSequence its working without CORS Issue only for GET Request , For Post its showing following error : """ Relay Utils Error while building Passthrough stream org.apache.axiom.om.OMException: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError Message : premature end of file  """ .What can i have to configure

Comment: Which version ur using ??

Comment: WSO2 ESB 4.8.1  and  WSO2 DSS 3.2.1